# Share bandwidth equally

Tags: networking, server

I have a server with 100 Mbps bandwidth.

Clients with dynamic IPs could connect to web server and download large files

I need to use `tc` to allow them to use all bandwidth when they're dowloading alone or share bandwidth equally when downloading clients > 1

Never before worked with `tc`

I came up with :

```
tc qdisc del root dev ens3 default 10
tc qdisc add dev ens3 root handle 1: htb rate 100mbps
tc class add dev ens3 parent 1: classid 1:1 htb rate 10mbps ceil 90mbps
tc class add dev ens3 parent 1:1 classid 1:10 htb rate 10mbps ceil 90mbps
```

But when two clients start downloading then they share 10mbps bandwidth

I need when

```
1 client - max 100 Mbps
2 clients - max 50 Mbps each
3 clients - max 33 Mbps each
4 clients - max 25 Mbps each
...
```

How to make it work?

---

Edit:
Forgot to add

There are maximum **10 clients** who can download simultaneously

And I guarantee 10 Mbps bandwidth for each client

Comment: *Why*? Bandwidth will be shared by default. It will not be completely fair, but the internet tends not to be completely fair with regards to routing and such. Additionally, a CDN will effectively remove such bottlenecks. Seems that a better solution would be to upgrade to 1GbE or 10GbE + CDN?

Comment: @vidarlo It's the best solution but I don't have such powers to upgrade. Most bandwidth shares to the first who starts downloading, Usually I see that the first one receives 60-80 Mbps